# Does performing cross-validation train the model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


boston = pd.read_csv('boston.csv')

x = boston.drop('medv', axis=1).values
y = boston['medv'].values


reg = LinearRegression()

cross_val_score(reg, x, y, cv=5)

reg.predict(x)
```

In the above code, I calculate the 5 - fold cross-validation score for my Linear Regression regressor. But when I try using the `predict()` method, I get an error saying:

```
This LinearRegression instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with 
appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

I thought the regressor is fit while performing cross-validation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fit your data first:

```
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)
```